# Spring Netflix Hystrix turbine.stream filter by cluster does not work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

Spring Boot: 1.3.3.RELEASE

Spring Cloud: Brixton.RC2

Hystrix Metrices sent via Rabbit from multiple Apps.

On the dashboard side filter by cluster
..../turbine.stream?cluster=[clusterName]

shows metrics from ALL sending apps.

This should filter by appId (clusterName) ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/166) that hasn't been completed.